# No Tx on Wsit-X

Tags: equipment-troubleshooting, wsjt-x, wspr, windows

Installed Wsit-X on windows 10, it only transmits when I press tune, However, It is not transmitting even when I press Enable Tx or Tx Next or both.

Comment: Did you mean WSJT-X?

Comment: You'll probably have to tell us what kind of radio you connected to your PC

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you have your Callsign programmed in?